# Visual bug when input is autofilled

Tags: css, forms, autofill, html-input

I have an html form with a bunch of inputs. When an input gets autofilled by Safari and I then attempt to edit the input there is a weird overlapping of the string.

[image]

If I click around it seems to fix itself, but it's not after the first click or when I simply focus on another input. I will attach the styles affecting my inputs. Not sure if this is my error or a bug in Safari, but it doesn't seem to happen on other input fields...

```css
input:is([type="text"],[type="number"],[type="email"],[type="tel"],[type="url"],[type="date"]),select {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    margin: 0;
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 2.75em;
    border: var(--approx-1px) solid var(--color-gray);
    border-radius: 0;
    padding: var(--spacing-default);
    color: var(--color-darkblue);
    font-size: 1em;
    font-family: inherit;
    text-align: center;
    text-align-last: center;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    position: relative;
}
:is(input,select):is(:hover,:focus) {
    border-color: var(--color-darkblue);
    outline: transparent;
}
```

Thanks for any ideas.

Comment: This issue seems to be related to Safari's autocomplete feature. Why not set `autocomplete="off"`.

Comment: It's a convenience feature for users and doesn't exactly feel right to turn it off because of what may be a styling issue. If this is a known bug and someone can cite it then I will probably just accept it, but I am leaning that is probably my stylings conflicting with the autofill's styling. If someone know how to fix it, be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after a bit of investigation I discovered the issue lied when the `::-webkit-contacts-auto-fill-button` appeared, it would push the input to the left and cause a graphical glitch. Well I didn't know we could target that pseudo element, but you can. Setting it to `position: absolute;` and scooting it over with `right: /* padding being used on the input */ ;` lets it "float" above the input field taking out of the flow, preventing the graphical glitch. Hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 0):

```css
input:-webkit-autofill, 
input:-webkit-autofill:hover,
input:-webkit-autofill:active,
input:-webkit-autofill:focus {
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 0px 9999px white;
}
```

This will add a white background to the input fields when they are autofilled, which may prevent the overlapping text issue. You can adjust the colors as per need.

###### I'm not that friendly with Safari so I just gave one suggestion.

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't solve it.